# Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert

Tags: solidity, contract-development, transactions, truffle

Getting a `Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert` error when migrating or testing a tutorial smart contract on Truffle in the terminal. I'm currently going through a tutorial creating and deploying a basic tic-tac-toe game on Ethereum. The fact that I'm getting this error when I'm migrating as well as when I'm testing leads me to believe that the problem is with the smart contract code and not the test code. Here's the full error:

```
Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert
at Object.InvalidResponse (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/web3/lib/web3/errors.js:38:1)
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/web3/lib/web3/requestmanager.js:86:1
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/truffle-core/~/truffle-migrate/index.js:225:1
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/truffle-provider/wrapper.js:134:1
at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/web3/lib/web3/httpprovider.js:128:1)
at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:64:1)
at XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:354:1)
at XMLHttpRequest._onHttpResponseEnd (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:509:1)
at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:469:1)
at emitNone (events.js:111:20)
at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:208:7)
at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1064:12)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:218:9)
```

The contract seemed to work well on Remix in the JS VM, and the code of my smart contract and of my JavaScript test matches the tutorial exactly. I looked online for a bit and saw that this error usually stems from a `require` issue, but I have 9 different `require`s in my contract and none seem to be obviously causing the issue. Again, I believe the issue is with the smart contract and not the JS test, but the JS test is here for reference: https://github.com/tomw1808/blocktactoe/blob/master/test/1_simple_test.js.

Here's my version info:

```
Truffle v4.1.7 (core: 4.1.7)
Solidity v0.4.23 (solc-js)
```

Here's my smart contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

contract TicTacToe {
    uint constant public gameCost = 0.1 ether;

    uint8 public boardSize = 3;
    uint8 movesCounter;

    bool gameActive;

    address[3][3] board;

    address public player1;
    address public player2;

    uint balanceToWithdrawPlayer1;
    uint balanceToWithdrawPlayer2;

    uint timeToReact = 3 minutes;
    uint gameValidUntil;

    address activePlayer;

    event PlayerJoined(address player);
    event NextPlayer(address player);
    event GameOverWithWin(address winner);
    event GameOverWithDraw();
    event PayoutSuccess(address receiver, uint amountInWei);

    function TicTacToe() public payable {
        player1 = msg.sender;
        require(msg.value == gameCost);
        gameValidUntil = now+timeToReact;
    }

    function joinGame() public payable {
        assert(player2 == address(0));
        gameActive = true;

        require(msg.value == gameCost);

        player2 = msg.sender;
        PlayerJoined(player2);
        if(block.number % 2 == 0) {
            activePlayer = player2;
        } else {
            activePlayer = player1;
        }

        gameValidUntil = now + timeToReact;

        NextPlayer(activePlayer);
    }

    function getBoard() public view returns(address[3][3]) {
        return board;
    }

    function setWinner(address player) private {
        gameActive = false;
        //emit an event
        GameOverWithWin(player);
        uint balanceToPayOut = address(this).balance;
        if(player.send(balanceToPayOut) != true) {
            if(player == player1) {
                balanceToWithdrawPlayer1 = balanceToPayOut;
            } else {
                balanceToWithdrawPlayer2 = balanceToPayOut;
            }
        } else {
            PayoutSuccess(player, balanceToPayOut);
        }
        //transfer money to the winner
    }

    function withdrawWin() public {
      uint balanceToTransfer;
        if(msg.sender == player1) {
            require(balanceToWithdrawPlayer1 > 0);
            balanceToTransfer = balanceToWithdrawPlayer1;
            balanceToWithdrawPlayer1 = 0;
            player1.transfer(balanceToTransfer);

            PayoutSuccess(player1, balanceToTransfer);
        } else {

            require(balanceToWithdrawPlayer2 > 0);
            balanceToTransfer = balanceToWithdrawPlayer2;
            balanceToWithdrawPlayer2 = 0;
            player2.transfer(balanceToTransfer);
            PayoutSuccess(player2, balanceToTransfer);
        }
    }

    function setDraw() private {
        gameActive = false;
        GameOverWithDraw();

        uint balanceToPayOut = address(this).balance/2;

        if(player1.send(balanceToPayOut) == false) {
            balanceToWithdrawPlayer1 += balanceToPayOut;
        } else {
            PayoutSuccess(player1, balanceToPayOut);
        }
        if(player2.send(balanceToPayOut) == false) {
            balanceToWithdrawPlayer2 += balanceToPayOut;
        } else {
            PayoutSuccess(player2, balanceToPayOut);
        }

    }

    function emergecyCashout() public {
        require(gameValidUntil < now);
        require(gameActive);
        setDraw();
    }


    function setStone(uint8 x, uint8 y) public {
        require(board[x][y] == address(0));
        require(gameValidUntil > now);
        assert(gameActive);
        assert(x < boardSize);
        assert(y < boardSize);
        require(msg.sender == activePlayer);
        board[x][y] = msg.sender;
        movesCounter++;
        gameValidUntil = now + timeToReact;

        for(uint8 i = 0; i < boardSize; i++) {
            if(board[i][y] != activePlayer) {
                break;
            }
            //win
            if(i == boardSize - 1) {
                //winner
                setWinner(activePlayer);
                return;
            }
        }
        for(i = 0; i < boardSize; i++) {
            if(board[x][i] != activePlayer) {
                break;
            }
            //win

            if(i == boardSize - 1) {
                //winner
                setWinner(activePlayer);
                return;
            }
        }

        //diagonale
        if(x == y) {
            for(i = 0; i < boardSize; i++) {
                if(board[i][i] != activePlayer) {
                    break;
                }
                //win
                if(i == boardSize - 1) {
                    //winner
                    setWinner(activePlayer);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

        //anti-diagonale
        if((x+y) == boardSize-1) {
            for(i = 0; i < boardSize; i++) {
                if(board[i][(boardSize-1)-i] != activePlayer) {
                    break;
                }
                //win

                if(i == boardSize - 1) {
                    //winner
                    setWinner(activePlayer);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

        //draw
        if(movesCounter == (boardSize**2)) {
            //draw
            setDraw();
            return;
        }

        if(activePlayer == player1) {
            activePlayer = player2;
        } else {
            activePlayer = player1;
        }
        NextPlayer(activePlayer);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's probably due to compiler changes after the tutorial was published. You should add information about your Truffle release (`$ truffle version`) and also exactly what you're using for Ethereum (geth, ganache-cli, parity, something else, and the version). Someone will probably spot the issue and help you fix it.

Comment: Thanks! I haven't yet deployed to Ethereum but was planning on interacting with it using MetaMask.

Truffle v4.1.7 (core: 4.1.7)
Solidity v0.4.23 (solc-js)

Comment: That's quite new. In Remix, you can see the compiler raises warnings about syntax when you force the compiler to `0.4.23` (why I personally dislike using `^` in the `pragma`. The warnings should not normally rise to the level of preventing you from deploying it. You're going to need something like Ethereum running for the migration to succeed. Consider `ganache-cli` in another window. You might also back away from the cutting edge by installing truffle at `4.1.3` with `solc 0.4.19` which compiles your contract without complaints.